# Generating DSP filter coefficients in C/Java for time-domain convolution

Tags: java, android, iphone, signal-processing, fft

I am writing a smartphone (Android, iPhone) application that does some DSP. I am an experienced programmer. I've also taken one undergraduate EE class in DSP and know how to use Matlab.

I would like to apply low pass and band pass filters to my time-domain signal. From my understanding, I need to perform convolution of my time-domain samples and filter coefficients. In Matlab, I would use the fir1() function to get the filter coefficients and the conv()/filter() functions to apply the convolution.

I know how to write the convolution function in Java/C, but **I don't know how to generate the filter coefficients**. I know that for the low-pass filter, the coefficients come from a sinc function, and the bandpass filter is basically a shifted low-pass filter. **How can I programmatically generate these coefficients?**

Answer (score 1):

There is code for generating FIR coefficients for low-pass and band-pass filters using the windowed-sinc method [on the nicholson.com dsp web page](http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/dsp.html#2).  The code is about 10 lines of old-fashioned Basic, but should be trivially convertible to C or Java.  There is an explanation on that page if you want to re-derive the code.

The art, when using a windowed-sinc, is in choosing the best window.  The more modern method, that requires less guess-work, is to use the Remez-exchange algorithm to generate the filter from specs.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a tutorial that generates filter coefficients in C++ code which should be relatively easy to translate into Java code. The tutorial can be found here: http://baumdevblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/butterworth-lowpass-filter-coefficients.html. I hope it is of some use for you.

It's quite an interesting subject and I am considering doing a similar project myself soon :)

Comment: This looks like coefficients for an Infinite Impulse Response (IIR) filter where as filter implemented with convolution is a Finite Impulse Response (FIR) operation requiring different techniques to generate filter taps.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you expect the filter parameters (bandwidth, transition band, etc.) to change, the simplest technique is to generate the coefficients in matlab and hard code them in your program. You'll find that matlab can generate good filters with significantly fewer coefficients that the window method can. Given that convolution is an MxN (M=number of filter coefficients and N is the number of samples) order operation, reducing M can make a big difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have successfully used a version of the Parks-McClennan method (Remez exchange) written in C by [Jake Janovetz](http://www.janovetz.com/jake/) to programatically generate coefficients for a bandpass FIR filter. You could give that a try.